# Cannot use these 2 functions with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am having a problem with my android code.

Following methods give error when using fragments:
   1. getSystemService()
   2. getCurrentFocus()

Here is the image so you guys can know where exactly the error is:
[Android Studio Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBXvc.png)

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)

```
package com.saipriyank.taxdiscount;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class discount_frag extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "discount_Frag";
    double num1, num2, sum;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.discount_frag,container,false);

        final EditText txtnum1 = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.txtnum1);
        final EditText txtnum2 = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.txtnum2);
        final Button bt = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.bt);
        final TextView tvAmount = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvAmount);
        final TextView tvTotal = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvTotal);

        return view;


        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

                try
                {
                    num1 = Double.parseDouble(txtnum1.getText().toString());
                    num2 = Double.parseDouble(txtnum2.getText().toString());
                    sum = (num1 * num2) / 100;
                    tvAmount.setText(Double.toString(sum));

                    tvTotal.setText(Double.toString(num1 - sum));
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"The fileds can not be empty.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }





            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: try set context.getSystemService or getContext.getSystemService

Answer (score 1):

Try using `getActivity()` before the method.

```
getActivity().getSystemService();
getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is normal because you are in a fragment and these are methods of an Activity instance. Just get activity instance and call these methods using that.

```
    getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
    getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    //or
    getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```